# Problemas com o comando php artisan utilizando o Laradock

Tags: laravel, docker

Sempre que eu utilizo o comando artisan do Laravel no meu workspace do laradock para criar um controller, uma model ou qualquer outro arquivo eu não consigo nem salvar e nem deletar este arquivo gerado, o sistema (Linux Mint) me pede pra colocar a minha senha de usuário.
Eu já tentei mudar a permissão da pasta do meu projeto pelo workspace e pelo próprio sistema, mas sempre que eu executo o comando artisan esta permissão muda e o problema persiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para você conseguir criar arquivos sem precisar ficar trocando a permissão toda vez, entre no workspace usando o comando:

```
docker-compose exec --user=laradock workspace bash
```

Comment: Pelo visto resolveu o problema. Muito obrigado, mesmo.